# Speeding up Samsung RC730 laptop - can I put second hard drive into it (SSD)?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I am heavy user, and I need more speed than I get from stock 5400 rpm hard drive. I want to buy SSD (I have one on desktop, and speed improvement is enormous). Here is the question - can I have 2 disks? One stock, slow, but with big space (640 GB - comparing to SSD it is relatively big), and second SSD, fast, small and keep there OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most laptops have only one drive bay.  Laptops with dual drive bays are quite rare.

I cannot find any detailed specifications on your laptop to suggest that it is capable of fitting two drives inside.  You should have a look at the [manual for your laptop](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-RC730-S02AT-downloads) and see what it says about installing hard drives.

If you have only one hard drive bay then your only option may be to get a USB hard drive enclosure (enclosures without the drive are quite cheap) and installing your current hard drive in that to use for storage.

Comment: According to manual, I have 2 slots for hard drives. So I checked it in my laptop, and it's true. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple options...

- There are kits to replace the optical drive with a hard drive such as [this](http://www.ipc-computer.eu/it-pi-n-Bracket_Kit_incl_500GB_HDD_to_replace_ODD_device_for_Samsung_RC730_S08-cP-63047-pId-3780800.html).  I can't speak to this one in particular (it was at the top of a google search), but you can probably find other options.
- There are also hybrid drives that contain both larger capacity spinning platters and a smaller SSD built into one.  [Here](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100006742%2040000380&IsNodeId=1&Description=hybrid&name=Laptop%20Hard%20Drives&Order=BESTMATCH) is a search on newegg for that type.

Answer (score 2):

You've most likely already performed this, but yes it is possible to install a second hard drive in the Samsung RC730 laptop. It actually has an extra bay and the box itself comes with installation brackets and a hdd cable... I have the same laptop upgraded with a 256SSD drive as the primary OS drive and used the stock HDD as a secondary file storage drive...

Adding the SSD drive makes the computer a completely different machine. I highly recommend it on this model as well as any other computer....

Comment: Important thing to note: only RC730 models that have +17" screen have 2 slots for hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

You want a hybrid drive which will give you the speed boost of SSD but also the capacity of a HDD. Something like the [Seagate Momentus](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/internal-hard-drives/laptop-hard-drives/momentus-xt-hybrid/) line.